mixed content error when communicating with rasa bot on aws ec2 from go daddy hosted wordpress website
I am working on developing a rasa chatbot for my company website.
The company website is hosted on Go daddy server and is built using Wordpress.
I built the bot with my custom data, deployed it on AWS ec2 instance, nginx to host and run the code.
I can access the bot via public ip address and can easily communicate with it.
I used rasa chat widget to deploy front end to wordpress using wpcode to add custom html to it.
Problem rises when I send a http access request to bot from this rasa chat widget.
It runs into mixed content error.
I have tried setting up nginx as a reverse proxy and allow cross orgin access. have added headers to nginx.conf file and script tests fine. still the same mixed content error.
what could be the possible solution for this?
can I ssl protect my aws ec2 instance so the secure connection can happen without obtaining a dns for ec2?
what else should I explore?
